# iPhone 13 Ear Pods Can't hear when using phone, but can hear YouTube videos

Tags: audio

My Ear Pods don't work with my iPhone 13 when making calls, but I can hear things like YouTube videos, etc.  I tried using a Plantronics Ear piece, and it worked fine.  The suggestions on the internet say to reboot the phone, disconnect and reconnect Ear Pods, but that doesn't help.

Comment: When on a call are you able to select them from the "audio" button?

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  Actually, the ear pods show up as being connected on the audio button.

Comment: Have you tried unpairing and re-pairing the AirPods to your iPhone? https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph561965261/ios

Comment: Kevin, Yes I've unpaired and repaired. It is so crazy.